# Mongodb $group returns only grouped item

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the about 20,000 documents in the following format where the value.day gives me the date

```
    { 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:11.000+0000"), 
    "value" : {
        "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:11.000+0000"), 
        "day_chan1" : 90.162, 
        "day_chan2" : 77.547, 
        "day_chan3" : 79.32, 
        "total_day_chan" : 247.029
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:23.000+0000"), 
    "value" : {
        "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:23.000+0000"), 
        "day_chan1" : 90.167, 
        "day_chan2" : 77.549, 
        "day_chan3" : 79.322, 
        "total_day_chan" : 247.038
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:35.000+0000"), 
    "value" : {
        "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:35.000+0000"), 
        "day_chan1" : 90.172, 
        "day_chan2" : 77.551, 
        "day_chan3" : 79.324, 
        "total_day_chan" : 247.047
    }
}
```

I want to perform an aggregation which would give me data from each day inside an array. Running the following command gives me two days but no data in them.

```
    db.temp4437190046D9electricity.aggregate([
      {
           $group: {
                '_id': '$value.day'
           }
      }
]);




  { "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z") }
```

How can I get the corresponding data for these two ids into these objects?

The expected output would look like

```
       { "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
             data: [{ 
    "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:11.000+0000"), 
    "day_chan1" : 90.162, 
    "day_chan2" : 77.547, 
    "day_chan3" : 79.32, 
    "total_day_chan" : 247.029
    }
    {
    "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:23.000+0000"), 
    "day_chan1" : 90.167, 
    "day_chan2" : 77.549, 
    "day_chan3" : 79.322, 
    "total_day_chan" : 247.038
    }
    { 
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:35.000+0000"), 
    "value" : {
    "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:35.000+0000"), 
    "day_chan1" : 90.172, 
    "day_chan2" : 77.551, 
    "day_chan3" : 79.324, 
    "total_day_chan" : 247.047
    }
    ]
     },
    { "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
      "data":[
    { 
        "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-05T14:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "day" : ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "time" : ISODate("2016-01-05T14:16:44.000+0000"), 
        "day_chan1" : 63.611, 
        "day_chan2" : 56.801, 
        "day_chan3" : 58.129, 
        "total_day_chan" : 178.541
    }
    { 
        "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-05T14:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "day" : ISODate("2016-01-05T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
        "time" : ISODate("2016-01-05T14:16:56.000+0000"), 
        "day_chan1" : 63.644, 
        "day_chan2" : 56.833, 
        "day_chan3" : 58.161, 
        "total_day_chan" : 178.638
    }
]

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your expected output from those sample documents?

Comment: @chridam added an expected result

Comment: `$group` will collapse/merge documents with same `value.day` into single document for output. So, for each output document you need to define some "aggregate function" that will derive values of output document from all those merged documents. An aggregate function like `$push` will simple collect merged documents properties in an array.

Answer (score 1):

This command will you the expected output. [$push](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator is missing from your aggregation command.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
         '$group' : {
             '_id': '$value.day',
             'data': {                                    
                 '$push' : '$value'
             }
         }

    }
]).pretty()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) accumulator operator in the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage to return an array of *value* for each document in a group of documents that share the same group by key; here `value.day`.  Also you shouldn't use the [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.ROOT) variable because for large collection the resulting documents may exceed the [BSON Document Size limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size).

```js
db.temp4437190046D9electricity.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$value.day",
        "data": { "$push": 
            { 
                "hour" : "$value.hour", 
                "day" : "$value.day", 
                "time" : "$value.time", 
                "day_chan1" : "$value.day_chan1", 
                "day_chan2" : "$value.day_chan2",  
                "day_chan3" : "$value.day_chan3", 
                "total_day_chan" : "$value.total_day_chan"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Using the sample data you provided yields:

```js
{
    "_id" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
    "data" : [
            {
                    "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00Z"),
                    "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
                    "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:11Z"),
                    "day_chan1" : 90.162,
                    "day_chan2" : 77.547,
                    "day_chan3" : 79.32,
                    "total_day_chan" : 247.029
            },
            {
                    "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00Z"),
                    "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
                    "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:23Z"),
                    "day_chan1" : 90.167,
                    "day_chan2" : 77.549,
                    "day_chan3" : 79.322,
                    "total_day_chan" : 247.038
            },
            {
                    "hour" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:00Z"),
                    "day" : ISODate("2016-01-04T00:00:00Z"),
                    "time" : ISODate("2016-01-04T23:00:35Z"),
                    "day_chan1" : 90.172,
                    "day_chan2" : 77.551,
                    "day_chan3" : 79.324,
                    "total_day_chan" : 247.047
            }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and the problem with this is that I get an array where the first two values are from different dates. Totally confused on what I am doing wrong,

Comment: @Bazinga777 I've updated the answer with the result.